# Show that if $X$ is an integrable random variable, then $\lim_{x\to \infty} x P(|X|\gt x)=0$.

Tags: probability-theory

Show that if $X$ is an integrable random variable, then $\lim_{x\to \infty} x P(|X|\gt x)=0$.

Attempt:

$P(|X|\gt x)= 2-F_Y(x)-F_X(x)$ where $Y=-X$, how to proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $$x \mathbb{P}(|X|>x) = \int_{\{|X|>x\}}x \, d\mathbb{P} \leq \int_{\{|X|>x\}} |X| \, d\mathbb{P}$$ the claim follows from the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: is there a way to not use the dominated convergence theorem? like using the definition of integrable random variable and maybe survivor function (1-CDF)

Comment: @jamesblack What do you mean by survivor function? I'm not aware of a proof which doesnt use a convergence theorem, but that doesn't mean that such a proof doesn't exist. (If you want to do measure theory, there will be no way around the dominated convergence theorem, just as a side remark.)