# If $E[X^p] < \infty$, then $\lim_{x\to \infty} x P(|X|\gt {x}^{1/p})=0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950658/show-that-if-x-is-an-integrable-random-variable-then-lim-x-to-infty-x-p), the proof of the following claim was solved:

If $E[X] < \infty$, then $\lim_{x\to \infty} x P(|X|\gt x)=0$ .

Now, I want to ask about the following claim:

If $E[X^p] < \infty$, then $\lim_{x\to \infty} x P(|X|\gt {x}^{1/p})=0$ .

I think this statement is true for $^\forall p>0$, but I couldn't prove it. Maybe I can prove it similarly to the former statement.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens if you take $X=Y^p$ in the one you know?  Question:  You wrote both $X$ and $|X|$ in there, why?  If $X$ can have negative values, does $E[X] < \infty$ allow the possibility $E[X] = -\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the first statement with $X$ changed to $|X|^{p}$ we see that $E|X|^{p}  <\infty$ implies $xP(|X|^{p} >x) \to 0$ or $x P(|X| >x^{1/p}) \to 0$.